# How to get the key and value not overwritten inside a for loop in an object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, function

I have this function that takes two lists as arguments. The first letter of each element of the list "L" is the identification of a book category. For example, "BKWR" and "BTSQ" are same category books because they start with the same letter "B". The positive integer separated by space is the number of books in that category. Now what the function does is that it takes the first list and matches from the second list whether the book category starting with the letter is present or not. If it is present then it sums the number. For example in the list "L" two book categories starting with "B" are present so it is supposed to sum them.

However, rather than summing the two, my function is overwriting the value of the previous "B" category. How can I stop it from overwriting the value?

```js
function extract(list,stocklist){
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < stocklist.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
      if (stocklist[i] == list[j][0]){
        newArr.push(list[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  let selected = newArr.map((item) => item.split(' '));
  let extracted = {};
  for (let k = 0; k < selected.length; k++){
    for (let l = 0; l < selected[k].length-1; l++){
        let key = selected[k][l][0];
        let value = selected[k][l+1];
        extracted[key] =  value;
    }
  }
  
  return extracted;
}

let L = ["ABAR 200", "CDXE 500", "BKWR 250", "BTSQ 890", "DRTY 600"];
let M = ["A", "B", "W"];

console.log(extract(L,M));
```

Comment: Maybe try adding the new value to the old value, instead of just assigning it?

Comment: You don't do any addition in your code. You certainly change the array index value (`l + 1`), but that isn't adding anything to you value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's already a value for the key, add to it instead of overwriting it. So change

```
extracted[key] =  value;
```

to

```
if (key in extracted) {
    extracted[key] += parseInt(value);
} else {
    extracted[key] = parseInt(value);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was confused about how to add the value tried looking up and watching some videos on objects and revisiting the chapter but couldn't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to add the "value" to your `extracted` object:

```js
function extract(list,stocklist){
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < stocklist.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++){
      if (stocklist[i] == list[j][0]){
        newArr.push(list[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  let selected = newArr.map((item) => item.split(' '));
  let extracted = {};
  for (let k = 0; k < selected.length; k++){
    for (let l = 0; l < selected[k].length-1; l++){
        let key = selected[k][l][0];
        let value = selected[k][l+1];
        if(value) {
         extracted[key] = (+extracted[key] || 0) + +value;
       }
    }
  }
  
  return extracted;
}

let L = ["ABAR 200", "CDXE 500", "BKWR 250", "BTSQ 890", "DRTY 600"];
let M = ["A", "B", "W"];

console.log(extract(L,M));
```

Comment: Thank you. It resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the minor part you are missing. Check the key and sum up, or simply assign the first value like:

```js
extracted[key] = extracted[key] ? extracted[key] + Number(value) : Number(value);
```

Comment: Thank you! This also resolved the issue.